# Nested table object usage in FORALL in oracle

Tags: oracle, nested-table, forall

I am trying to insert data from a collection into the table using `FORALL`, I expected the process to be fast but unfortunately process is rather slow and didn't show any major performance improvement.

Below code:

```
create or replace Procedure data_test (E in nchar, J in number)
      AS

      Exec_data JR_Table;   //Created a nested table variable
      
      BEGIN
      
    select JR_Type (job_id, e_id,  USER_NAME, start_time, end_time)
                    bulk collect into Exec_data   //Bulk collect into this variable
                    from ( taBLE);
                    
                    
                     FORALL counter in Exec_data.first..Exec_data.last    //insert using FORALL
                insert into DATA_TEMP1 Values
                (Exec_data(counter).JOB_ID, Exec_data(counter).E_ID, Exec_data(counter).START_TIME, Exec_data(counter).END_TIME;
    
                commit;
                
                End;
```

Above doesn't produce any satisfactory results with just 1300 records to insert in table and time taken is 6min, Instead I want to try using FORALL in below way:

```
FORALL counter in Exec_data.first..Exec_data.last    //insert using FORALL
                    insert into DATA_TEMP1 Values
                    (Exec_data(counter));
```

Expecting above code change will speed up the process.

When tried to compile the code getting error:

> Error(474,33): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -

I am sure their should be a way to get this work. I am not a core Oracle developer, I was able to write the above code by studying in few sites.

Comment: There must be some Indexes or Triggers associated with this table. Since both of them make DML statements slow, Try to disable all indexes and triggers first and then try to execute the code. That might speed up the query.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai thanks for the reply, Can you help to explain more on how disabling the index and trigger will help to speedup the query. Also i am facing hard time to insert data in to normal table from nested table directly, if you can see the `FORALL` loop I am trying to use statement in this way `insert into DATA_TEMP1 Values
                    (Exec_data(counter))` expecting it will speed up the process but getting inconsistant datatype issue. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: What is the table structure for DATA_TEMP1? Is it exactly what Exec_data(counter) has?

Comment: @Namandeep_Kaur yes exactly same as  Exec_data(counter)

Comment: What exactly does it say here:
Error(474,33): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -'
What was expected and what did it get?
Also, correct me if I missed it but your code seems to be missing the parenthesis after END_TIME
(Exec_data(counter).JOB_ID, Exec_data(counter).E_ID, Exec_data(counter).START_TIME, Exec_data(counter).END_TIME;

How did it show the result?